# springtoolsuite update caused all programs to fail with Error: Could not find or load main class java

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I just did a check for updates with spring tool suite and all of a sudden none of my programs work and I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class java
```

I tried all suggestions of update server config properties but this did not help. Please advice needed here; all production stuff has stopped. is this a VMWare tc server issue or not?

I decided to EDIT this post and past the exact error as I cannot find any resolution as yet to the web applications that do not work due to this error;

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.
EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector was @Import'ed but is not 
annotated with @Configuration nor does it declare any @Bean methods; 
 it does not implement ImportSelector or 
 extend    ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar. Update the class to meet one 
 of these requirements or do not attempt to @Import it. 
  servlet-context.xml   /VSEsperAPI/src/main/
   webapp/WEB-  INF/spring/appServlet   Unknown Spring Beans Problem
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors in the problems or markers view?

Comment: you can try to start STS with a "-clean" option, maybe that helps (if the problem is caused by the "check for updates" action. Otherwise, check your JRE configs in STS, maybe something got into a stale state.

Comment: and it would be useful to know whether there are errors showing up in the problems or marker view (as mentioned above) and when exactly the problem occurs (when launching a random plain Java project with a main class, when starting up tc server, etc.)